C# TCP Socket for File Transfer - Many Small Packets vs One Big Packet
I'm building a full-stack application where the server is to be capable of maintaining connections with multiple clients at the same time. Communication will be done via TCP-IP. Since most of the data transferred will be very small, I've compromised to set the buffer to 4096 bytes for both ends.
However, entire files will eventually be transferred through this same connection. Since these files may potentially be multiple MB in size, I've been questioning myself: which is the best approach, to send one large packet or send many 4096B packets to the client?
In the case of using one big packet, how will the client deal with it given that the client's buffer is 4096 bytes as well? Will it "receive" many packets until the original packet is entirely consumed by the buffer or will the overflown data be lost?

"Many Small Sockets vs One Big Socket" - what is that supposed to mean? A socket is a socket is a socket. It has no "size".

The buffer size of a socket does not say that a socket can transfer at most that many bytes. I guess there is a huge misconception here about how sockets work or what they are for that matter.

Are you sure you want to build this yourself? Have you checked existing solution, like MQTT, AMPQ, gRPC, or just http and concluded that none of them fulfill your requirements?

I agree, building a custom TCP protocol is so full of pitfalls, see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html you really should not be doing this unless you have no other choice. Given you seem to lack even a basic understanding of how TCP sockets work, our concern seems to be warranted.

A socket represents the TCP connection itself. You don't send a socket. You send a data packet through a socket. Setting a buffer size on a socket has no bearing on the number of packets you can send. You can send as many packets as you want. So, to send a large file, you simply break it up into smaller chucks and send each chunk one after the other. It is also possible to send multiple files in parallel over a single socket connection, by interweaving the packets, and providing sufficient details on each packet to identify which file it belongs to.

Thanks all for the comments!
I'm aware that my knowledge on connectivity is lacking and that perhaps choosing an already build solution for this would be ideal, but I'm using this project mainly as a learning opportunity for me.
I believe I worded the issue poorly. "Sending one PACKET" instead of a Socket would indeed be better suited for this. I'll edit my question accordingly.
So, considering @RemyLebeau 's comment, the best approach would be to break the file down into chunks and send multiple smaller packets instead of a singular large packet?

@Cacangale Except for extremely small files, you can never send a whole file in a single packet. TCP is a stream, and any given write can accept fewer bytes than requested, so you have to be prepared to loop through the file sending chunks in multiple writes.

@RemyLebeau okay, great! Thank you very much!
